# Check for Null when looping through ArrayList in Template

Tags: silverstripe, silverstripe-4

I have a template that is looping through a GroupedList of data from an API (that I don't control)  in a template.  This has worked fine for a while, but now some of the elements in the loop are Null, instead of an array of data, resulting in an error.  If I check the fields themselves for Null. I get the same error.

```
Uncaught TypeError: method_exists(): Argument #1 ($object_or_class) must be of type object|string, null given


<% loop $indices %>
  <% if fileName %>
    $fileName
  <% end_if %>
<% end_loop %>
```

This error has cropped up since upgrading to php8 from 7.4 and running a composer update.

How can I check the loop item has data and is not Null?

Answer (score 0):

You might not control the API, but the `$indices` variable will be in some PHP you control, yes? I.e. you have some PHP code which gets data from the API and then passes it to the template.

I would recommend removing `null` values before passing to the template.

I am pretty sure there's no way to check if the current scope object is null in Silverstripe's templating language.

UPDATE: I think this PR will stop this scenario from triggering an exception: https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-framework/pull/10589